# Android MapView - Arrow overlay to destination

Tags: android-mapview

I would like to show a small arrow as an overlay from my source's marker pointing towards destination point. So this arrow should be pointing in all directions as the source location changes. It will be like a compass shown on source point pointing towards destination.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found for a similar problem is to use a image for the marker representing an arrow. Then I calculate the angle between the source and the destination and so I rotate the marker with this angle. (sorry for my english).

```java
protected class yourOverlay extends Overlay{
   public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when){
      super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
      Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.arrow);
      Point sourceCoords = new Point();
      mapView.getProjection().toPixels(sourcePosition, sourceCoords);
      int x = sourceCoords.x - bmp.getWidth()/2;
      int y = sourceCoords.y - bmp.getHeight();
      Point destinationCoords = new Point();
      mapView.getProjection().toPixels(destinationPosition, destinationCoords);
      double angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(sourceCoords.x - destinationCoords.x, sourceCoords.y - destinationCoords.y));
      Matrix matrix = new Matrix();         
      matrix.postRotate(-(float)angle, bmp.getWidth()/2,bmp.getHeight());
      matrix.postTranslate(x,y);
      canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, matrix, new Paint());
      return true;

    }
}
```